# sending email with default id without using intents

Tags: android, java

I am new to android, so I need a little bit of quick help. I tried this code from [here.](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android) There was no error but the problem arises in send fucntion's transport.send() Could you please rectify it. help will be much appreciated

```
my logcat file
01-02 22:59:27.603: D/gralloc_goldfish(755): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-02 22:59:31.013: V/hari(755): edittext texttype your mail here
01-02 22:59:31.723: I/Choreographer(755): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-02 22:59:35.463: V/hari(755): mail:007sanketh@gmail.com

01-02 22:59:35.782: D/dalvikvm(755): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 139K, 9% free 2875K/3132K, paused 29ms, total 41ms
01-02 22:59:36.172: V/sanketh(755): there
01-02 22:59:36.172: V/sanketh(755): username:007sanketh@gmail.com

01-02 22:59:36.182: V/sanketh(755): from add:007sanketh@gmail.com
01-02 22:59:36.182: V/sanketh(755): subject:This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device.
01-02 22:59:36.182: V/sanketh(755): body:Email body.
01-02 22:59:36.502: D/dalvikvm(755): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 368K, 14% free 3017K/3504K, paused 27ms, total 31ms
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755): Could not send email
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:365)
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.getLocalAddress(InternetAddress.java:517)
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at javax.mail.internet.UniqueValue.getUniqueMessageIDValue(UniqueValue.java:99)
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateMessageID(MimeMessage.java:2054)
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2076)
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2042)
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:117)
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at com.example.emailsendnoui.sending.send(sending.java:119)
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at com.example.emailsendnoui.MainActivitySecond.send_mail(MainActivitySecond.java:86)
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at com.example.emailsendnoui.MainActivitySecond.access$0(MainActivitySecond.java:73)
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at com.example.emailsendnoui.MainActivitySecond$1.onClick(MainActivitySecond.java:47)
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-02 22:59:36.502: E/MailApp(755):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 22:59:36.512: I/Choreographer(755): Skipped 274 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.


sending java file

package com.example.emailsendnoui;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.CommandMap;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

import android.util.Log;


public class sending extends javax.mail.Authenticator { 
  private String _user; 
  private String _pass; 

  private String[] _to; 
  private String _from; 

  private String _port; 
  private String _sport; 

  private String _host; 

  private String _subject; 
  private String _body; 

  private boolean _auth; 

  private boolean _debuggable; 

  private Multipart _multipart; 


  public sending() { 
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
    _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 

    _user = ""; // username 
    _pass = ""; // password 
    _from = ""; // email sent from 
    _subject = "testing"; // email subject 
    _body = "working condition"; // email body


    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
  } 

  public sending(String user, String pass) { 
    this(); 

    _user = user; 
    _pass = pass; 
  } 

  public boolean send() throws Exception {

    Properties props = _setProperties();
    Log.v("sanketh","there");
 String sent="no success";
 Log.v("sanketh","username:"+_user);
 Log.v("sanketh","password:"+_pass);
 //Log.v("sanketh","to add:"+_to[0]);
 Log.v("sanketh","from add:"+_from);
 Log.v("sanketh","subject:"+_subject);
 Log.v("sanketh","body:"+_body);
    if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) { 

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

      MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

      InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
      for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
      }

        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

      msg.setSubject(_subject); 
      msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

      // setup message body 
      BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

      messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
      _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

      // Put parts in message 
      msg.setContent(_multipart); 

      // send email
      //Transport.send(msg,_to);
      Transport.send(msg); 
      Log.v("sanketh","here");
      sent="success";
      return true;
    } else { 
      return false; 
    } 
  } 

  public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
  } 

  @Override 
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
  } 

  private Properties _setProperties() { 
    Properties props = new Properties(); 

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

    if(_debuggable) { 
      props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
    } 

    if(_auth) { 
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
    } 

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

    return props; 
  } 

  // the getters and setters 
  public String getBody() { 
    return _body; 
  } 

  public void setBody(String _body) { 
    this._body = _body; 
  } 

public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
this._to = toArr;
}

public void setFrom(String string) {
this._from = string;
}

public void setSubject(String string) {
this._subject = string;
}
  // more of the getters and setters ….. 
} 

class which creates and instantiates objects  of tht sending class

    private void send_mail()
    {
      sending m = new sending("username", "password"); 

      String[] toArr = {"asdadqwc@gmail.com", "sdasad@sdad.com"}; 
      m.setTo(toArr); 
      m.setFrom("we2342asd@gmail.com"); 
      m.setSubject("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device."); 
      m.setBody("Email body."); 

      try { 
        //m.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation"); 

        if(m.send()) { 
          Toast.makeText(this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        } else { 
          Toast.makeText(this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        } 
      } catch(Exception e) { enter code here
        //Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

You can't do network operations on the main thread.  Do them in an `AsyncTask`  or a background thread instead.

Answer (score 0):

for sending mail you are using network,network operations you cna't do in main thread that is why you are getting **android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException** so do the network operations in using **AsyncTask**  ,to know more details about using AsyncTask and about the exception you are getting visit link [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: whereever you are calling some activity or class to send mail that call you can make in AsycTask

Answer (score 0):

The exception you have got is NetworkOnMainThreadException. To overcome that problem you can add this code near your e mail function:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
        new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

For more info: [How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

//edit

This is how you use async task to get away with networkonmainthreadexception (sample code):

```
 private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

            private ApplicationListAdappter activity;
            private ImageView bmImage;

            public DownloadImageTask(ApplicationListAdappter applicationListAdappter, ImageView imageView) {
                this.activity = applicationListAdappter;
                this.bmImage = imageView;
            }

            protected void onPreExecute() {

            }

            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
                String urldisplay = urls[0];
                Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
                try {
                    InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                    mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error", "image download error");
                }
                return mIcon11;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
        }
```

execute the async task:

```
DownloadImageTask loadImages = new DownloadImageTask(ApplicationListAdappter.this, imageView);
loadImages.execute(ap.getIconURL());
```

Comment: this one works but could someone just say where do i use async task on i mean on which class

Comment: I have edited the answer. you mentioned the previous answer works. if it is so accept the answer.